# When I connect a joystick, my pointer is moved

Tags: gamepad, joystick

I'm trying to play a game with a Microsoft Sidewinder (presicion racing wheel and pedals). The pointer moves alone but, when I push a pedal, it stops moving.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the joystick input driver:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-joystick && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```

Then reboot.

Comment: it doesn't work :C how I can uninstall the driver?

Comment: `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-joystick`

Comment: Does it work now?